# "column XYZ must be in group by" --> "cannot group by aggregate column"

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate, sum

i have trouble with following sql-statement (trimmed):

```
SELECT nr,
    (CASE WHEN 
        SUM(vkdtab.amount*liter)<>0 AND 
        jjjjmm BETWEEN 201001 and 201009 
    THEN SUM(net)/SUM(vkdtab.amount*liter) 
    ELSE 0 END) as return
FROM tab
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

It should give me the amount/liter of items in a special timeframe, but I get the error: `column return must be in group by`

After I add that column: `cannot group by aggregate column`.

This is functional, just without the timeframe:

```
CASE WHEN 
    SUM(vkdtab.amount*liter)<>0
THEN SUM(net)/SUM(vkdtab.amount*liter) 
ELSE 0 END
```

How can I add the timeframe without getting an error?

Comment: What RDBMS is this? I've not seen the syntax `GROUP BY 1,2,3` before.

Comment: @Martin Smith: MySQL apparently allows it.

Comment: Is it just me or are you referncing a table that isn't in your query? Where is the join to vkdtab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try changing the GROUP BY to `GROUP BY nr, jjjjmm` so it matches your unaggregated columns in the SELECT clause. You either GROUP BY or SUM/MIN/COUNT etc

If this is wrong, then the aggregate is wrong because it would fail the "express your aggregate in plain english" test

`GROUP BY ordinal` is a vile concept too and should be shot.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was incorrect - you cannot use `HAVING` in this scenario

You just need to put in the where clause:

```
SELECT nr,
    (CASE WHEN 
        SUM(vkdtab.amount*liter)<>0 AND 
        jjjjmm BETWEEN 201001 and 201009 
    THEN SUM(net)/SUM(vkdtab.amount*liter) 
    ELSE 0 END) as return
FROM tab

Where jjjjmm BETWEEN 201001 and 201009
And jjjjmm BETWEEN 201013 and 201020

GROUP BY CASE WHEN 
    SUM(vkdtab.amount*liter)<>0
THEN SUM(net)/SUM(vkdtab.amount*liter) 
ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: um, should it be Where jjjjmm BETWEEN 201001 and 201009
OR jjjjmm BETWEEN 201013 and 201020?